# How to extract text/data from PDF with embedded fonts

Tags: c#, pdf

I have PDF, Indian language(Kannada) is used in it, but when I copy the text from PDF and paste it into the notepad  the content is showing as square boxes. I tried reading  pro-grammatically using iTextSharp but no luck . 
I checked its properties and it says Embedded Fonts with Subset (Arial Unicode MS(True Type) - IDENTITY-H).

Does anyone have an idea how to extract the text from it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether your PDF contains sufficient information for text extraction? In the recent weeks there have been many questions concerning text extraction from PDFs containing Indian languages, and quite often the PDFs turned out to be generated with incomplete or false information concerning which glyph represents which character.

Comment: With IDENTITY-H encoding there is nothing you can do...It is a false charmap that (basically) uses font glyph indices instead of character values

Comment: Hi @mkl ,How to check whether PDF contains sufficient information for text extraction?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the text from Acrobat?

Comment: @markstephens ,yes I can copy text from PDF and paste it in any text editor. but the all text/content in notepad shows square boxes

Comment: @Lingaraj You have to inspect some internal objects of the PDF; this of course implies that you have to know your way around inside a PDF. First you check the font definitions in the PDF. In case of Kannada fonts their encoding most likely is IDENTITY-H. As user1654209 already mentioned, this encoding conveys no information on glyph - character relations. Thus, extra information is needed. This extra information may be given in a ToUnicode map. So you essentially have to check for that map. Whether the map is complete enough and correct, you find out by text extraction itself.

Comment: You say you can copy&paste *into any text editor* but that *notepad shows square boxes.* Is copy&pasting into other text editors more successful?

Comment: @mkl Yes I can paste it into other text editors also I tried pasting it in MS Word but same result. it shows text as below.                       

Comment: @Lingaraj Ok. Copy&paste from Adobe Reader failing sure is a bad sign. Have you inspected the fonts in your PDF concerning their encoding and their /ToUnicode map? Or can you provide the PDF in question for inspection?

Comment: @Lingaraj filehosting.org does not seem to work properly.

Comment: After deactivating the Adobe plugins in IE I finally could retrieve your PDF. I would not recommend using filehosting.org in their current state. That being said, your document provides the Indian glyphs by means of a font with IDENTITY-H encoding but without a /ToUnicode mapping. According to the PDF specification this implies that *there is no way to determine what* a *character code represents.* (Section 9.10.2 *Mapping Character Codes to Unicode Values* of [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))

Comment: @mkl I have used filehosting.org first time so didn't know about it, thanks for your suggestion hence forth I will not use this.  But its very sad :( I cannot extract the text from it. Anyways many thanks to you for your help.

Comment: You can still try rendering the PDF pages to a bitmap and ocr'ing it. i have not done that yet, though, myself.

Comment: @mkl , Hi Mkl I have got one clue from this PDF creator he said they have used Arial Unicode MS font to create these PDF. so my question is there anyway we can get this extracted correctly using Arial Unicode MS font?... thanks in advance

Comment: Not easily... When fonts are embedded into pdfs, the order of glyphs can be rearranged. If you have the identical version of the font file, though, you might by comparing glyphs be able to construct the mappings.